# Generic expression in java

Tags: java, jwt

I am trying to acquire claims from jwt token using jsonwebtoken.io JWTs library. 
Can't really think of a way to convert claims to ArrayList/List with generics. 
Is there is a better way to do this:

```
claims.get("authorities", List.class)
    .forEach(e -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(e.toString())));
```

I am basically looking for a way to generify List.class.

Answer (score 1):

yes, using java 8 streams

```
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = claims.get("authorities", List.class)
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(e.toString()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Just edited question, what I was looking is to generify List.class part, apparently, something like List<String>.class, the syntax seems to be wrong that way.

Comment: you can't do it